# Set environment variables to iTerm2 badges

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

I'm tinkering with iTerm2, trying to achieve the following:

1. switch to one of many profiles (e.g. work & personal);
2. set/unset environment variables based on the usage of the profiles;
3. make the badge read one or more of these "fluent" env vars.

Currently, I'm doing the "auto-assignment" of env vars by setting them at the start of each profile session:

[Settings -> Profiles -> General -> Send text at start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxHxI.png)

`export FOO="bar" && export FUZ="buz"`

I assume there's a better way to do it but that's what I came up with so far.

What I'm struggling with is creating a function that would read these env vars and assign their values to the badge content.

I read a lot of stuff online but nothing seems to work.

For the record, I'm using zsh.

If someone more experienced with configuring iTerm could pitch in, I'd appreciate it! :)